# Elegant way to get PDF download from file

Tags: php, fpdf

I got a file that when given a `?ordernummer=123456` fetches the necessary data from DB and generates a PDF file with FPDF that forces a download of the PDF. Works fine. Now i want to call this file from another page so that when a button or link is pressed it downloads the PDF file. Right now I'm using `include()`, it works but is not very elegant in my opinion. I've tried using `file_get_contents();` but thats not working either. Does anyone have a good solution?

```
$ordernummer = "204377";

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'ordernummer' => $ordernummer
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://url.nl/pdf/generate_pakbon.php', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Force Download" in PHP. This is done by setting the headers of your file correctly followed by reading the file in your PHP file.

**Forcing a download using PHP:**

In case of a PDF file, you'd need these headers:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=pakbon_".intval($_GET['ordernummer']).".pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

The `filename=` part is the filename you are forcing upon the download. So not the existing file.

After setting the headers, you can read the file using:

```
readfile('http://ledisvet.nl/pdf/generate_pakbon.php?ordernummer='.intval($_GET['ordernummer']);
```

If you add this to a document all together and call it 'downloadpakbon.php' you can simply link to `<a href="downloadpakbon.php?ordernummer=123456">download pakbon</a>` inside your page and the download will be force. Credits go to the example explained here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

**FPDF Only method:**

There are other ways available as well. FPDF has a method called 'Output' which you are probably using already. There are 4 possible parameters inside this method, one of the is 'D' which stands for forcing the download: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

One way to do it is to add an extra parameter to generate_pakbon.php like ?download=true and then basing the final output method on this parameter:

```
if($_GET['download'] === true) {
  $pdf->Output('Order123.pdf', 'D');
} else {
  $pdf->Output('Order123.pdf', 'I');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your link http://ledisvet.nl/pdf/generate_pakbon.php did download in my browser (Chrome). To ensure this isn't a browser-specific behaviour, add the following lines at the beginning of generate_pakbon.php (NB: ensure this is before any other output)

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pakbon.pdf");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

I would then move your quoted code into this php file.